# Ethernet connection not showing

Tags: networking, ethernet

Please help.
I have 15.04 version of UBUNTU. The problem that I am facing now is:
I am connected to the ethernet but it always shows that you are offline 
now. It never shows the lan connection logo.
Also I tried to boot new version of ubuntu 15.10. But In the installation
time itself it shows "you are disconnected now".
Will you please tell me where is the problem.
I am really frustrated now.
Please help me.

```
lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2:
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Device [1019:99d2]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

sudo iwconfig:
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.


dmesg |grep Network ;

[   16.207523] audit: type=1400 audit(1453555574.981:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=429 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   16.207529] audit: type=1400 audit(1453555574.981:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=429 comm="apparmor_parser"

ifconfig:

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 10:78:d2:05:9a:15  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:87 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:87 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:10724 (10.7 KB)  TX bytes:10724 (10.7 KB)

cat /etc/network/interfaces:



# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Please give us the output of `sudo iwconfig` and `dmesg | grep Network`.

Comment: **Please try the following** As a rule of thumb this is what is needed to do to start the diagnosis for this type of incidents 1. make sure the cable is not bent and that the jacks at both ends of the cable are not loose
2. if possible check using a second cable
3. if the problem persists Please answer : a. what network device are you using to connect the computer/laptop to the network ?

Comment: I have dual boot in my laptop with Window 8.1 and Ubuntu 15.04.
The lan is properly working with the lan cable  I have in Windows 8.1
But its not working in Ubuntu.

Comment: I have added the output.

Comment: Can you connect by Wi-Fi to install a driver?

Comment: And also please give output of `ifconfig; cat /etc/nertwork/interfaces`

Comment: what is the model of the laptop ?

Comment: Yes i can connect to a wifi.

Comment: HCL ME L 1014...

Comment: I have added the output....please check it

Answer (score 0):

Connect to internet using wifi and run in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms
```

Then reboot. This will install an alternative Ethernet driver for this adapter.